# Sum of digits of a product is equal to product - 9

Tags: algorithms

Say we have a number greater than or equal to 5 and less than 10, like 5.

If we multiply it by 2, we get 10, and if we take the sum of the digits of 10, we get 1.

If instead of adding up the digits of 10, we subtract 9, we also get 1.

Let's try another number, 6.

2 * 6 = 12 
Sum_of_digits(12) = 3 
12 - 9 = 3

For a number greater than or equal to five and less than 10, why does the sum of digits of a number times two equal to the same product - 9 ?

EDIT: Whoops, I made a typo. I meant "for a number less than or equal to five AND less than 10." Sorry!

Comment: why are both of the posted counterexamples $11$? what happened to $10$?

Comment: @Jonathan

In general, the difference between an even number and the sum of its digits is a multiple of 9. For example:
$12468 - 21 = 12447$ and it's clear that
$9\,{\large |}\,12447$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not true, only because the numbers get too large. For instance $2\cdot50$ has $1$ as the sum of its digits. However, there is a kernel of truth to your assertion, which has nothing to do with the multiplication by $2$ at the start.

The result underlying this curiosity is this:
**The sum of the digits of a positive integer is its remainder when dividing by $9$.**

Thus, if $n$ is given and you add its digits, the result is the same as subtracting a certain multiple of $9$ from $n$. If you pick $n$ to be a small enough number, then the only possible multiple of $9$ to use is $1\cdot 9$; this is why your statement in its exact form holds.

Comment: Why? Is there a proof for this?

Comment: @LeonHelmsley Yes, I will give a proof in this comment box. Write $n=\sum_{i=0}^k a_k10^k$. Then note that $10=9+1$, so (using the binomial theorem if you want) $n$ is some multiple of $9$ plus $\sum_{i=0}^k a_k$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't?

$2\times11=22$, sum_of_digits(22) $= 4 \neq 22-9 $

This works for the numbers $a$ from 5-9 because $2a = 10 + b$, which has the digit sum $1+b$, which is nine less than $10+b$.

Comment: Whoops. I meant for a number greater than or equal to five, and less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is very very wrong! You don't even have to check long enough to find the counterexample. For example, let us start with $11$, its double is $22$, sum of its digits is $4$ which is not $22-9$.

However you are true for the $n$ such that $5\leq n\leq 9$. Becuase double of these numbers fall between $10$ and $19$. And $1\times10+n-9=1+n$ for $0\leq n\leq9$

Comment: $9\,{\large |}\,\left(22 - 4\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x =a_{0} + 10a_{1} + \cdots + 10^{m}a_{m}\quad \mbox{is an even number}\,,
\
a_{n} = 0, 1,\ldots 9\,,\ n = 0,1,2\ldots,m\,,\ a_{0} \not= 1 
$$

$$
x
=
\left(a_{0} + \cdots + a_{m}\right)
+
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}\left(10^{n} - 1\right)a_{n}
$$
$$
x - \left(a_{0} + \cdots + a_{m}\right)
=
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}\left(10^{n} - 1\right)a_{n}
$$
Notice that $9\,{\large |}\,\left(10^{n} - 1\right)$ when $n \geq 1$.